# def() defined in a class are not executed

Tags: django, http

I defined a class that has a get method. When the user sends a request with the get method, the method fetches the data from the database, and then makes some changes and sends it to the user. However, I tried it. When the user initiates a get request, only the following two lines of code are executed

```
queryset = Product.objects.all()
serializer_class = ProductSerializer
```

and the get method is not executed.

```
## urls.py
router.register(r'getList', ProductListViewset)


## views.py

class ProductListViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = ProductSerializer
        data = serializer.data
        username = data.get('user_name')
        user = User.objects.get(username__exact=username)
        new_data = {
            'id': data.get('id'),
            'user_name': data.get('user_name'),
            'user_image_URL': user.get('user_image_URL'),
            'c_time': data.get('c_time'),
            'goods_price': data.get('goods_price'),
            'title': data.get('title'),
            'description': data.get('description')
        }
        return Response(new_data, 200)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the beginning, I defined the route in the following way：

```
# urls.py
from rest_framework import routers
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'getList', ProductListViewset)
app_name = 'product'
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'', include(router.urls)),
]
```

If I define a route this way, the framework already provides routing and action by default.Therefore, when the user sends a get request, it does not execute the get method I defined.I solved the problem in the following way：

```
app_name = 'product'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'getList', ProductListViewset.as_view({'get': 'get'})),
]
```